# OAuth with Dropbox API - Repeated App Confirmation

Tags: api, dropbox

Having this issue with my Dropbox App which is integrated with the OAUTH Dropbox API.

[Orangedox for Dropbox](https://dropbox.orangedox.com)

Application works fine except, everytime a user accesses the app (even after the first time) they are continuously prompted with a confirmation for the application to access their files and folders.  Is this expected behaviour? or should this only occur once when the user first accesses the application?

Anyone have experience with the Dropbox API?

[image: Screenshot Application Confirmation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what you're asking is why when you redirect the user to the auth page, they get prompted to "allow" the app even though they already have.

This app is using OAuth 1. Dropbox does do auto redirection for **OAuth 2** if the user has already authorized the app. So if you use OAuth 2 instead, a user who has already authorized your app will be forwarded directly back to the app instead of being asked to click the Allow button first.

Comment: ah I see .. hmm OAUTH 2 here we go!  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm using OAuth2 only, but still am getting the dialog permission box each time no matter I have logged in before. I'm testing it on localhost and the `redirect_uri` is matching the one i have entered in `APP CONSOLE`. I'm using `OAUTH2` similar to the project: 'https://github.com/dropbox/mdwebhook'. Please help me @smarx !

Comment: @ChadBrown, How did you solve the problem, I'm facing the same one even after using `OAUTH2`, please provide the code if you can. Thanks !

Comment: @softvar I believe we don't auto-redirect to localhost URIs. Try deploying this on a server with a non-localhost/non-127.0.0.1 address.

Comment: @smarx Oou! This is strange! I'll deploy it on `heroku` for testing and will report it here the after-come. Thanks!